# Adding a row to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to add a new row to my JSON when the user clicks a link. Here's my javascript: It's not erroring, but I am not getting updated JSON in my alert.

```
$(document).ready( function(){

people = {
    "COLUMNS":["NAME","AGE"],
    "DATA":[
    ["Jon","16"],
    ["Jerry","23"]
    ]
} 

members = people.DATA;
var nc = "<table border=1 width=500><tr><td>name</td><td>age</td><td></td></tr>";

for(var i=0;i<members.length;i++)
{
    nc+= '<tr><td>' + members[i][0] + '</td>';
    nc+= '<td>' + members[i][1] + '</td>';
    nc+= '<td><a href="" class="addlink">add a new person</a></td></tr>';
}

nc += "</table>";

$("#result").html(nc);

$(".addlink").click( function(){ 

    // add another row to our JSON
    people.DATA['NAME'] = "new";
    people.DATA['AGE'] = "99";

    alert(people.DATA);
    return false;

});
});
```

Comment: Actually, More code for this, or a Jsfiddle will help us help you!

Comment: That's not JSON, but merely an object literal.

Comment: Btw consider a [templating engine](http://handlebarsjs.com/). Creating HTML source code by manually concatenating strings is an awful way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not JSON, it's a Javascript object.

To add another item in the array, you create an array and add to it, as it is an array of arrays:

```
people.DATA.push(["new", "99"]);
```